# How does the chess24 rating compare to other server ratings?

Tags: rating

My question is how the chess24 blitz-rating compares to the rating of other servers, like ICC or the ChessBase server. And whether the chess24-rating inflated over the last few month.

The reason for my question is that I used to play a little on chess24 and I had a rating of around 2100, which is comparable to my blitz rating on ICC or on ChessBase. But now after a hiatus of a few month I blitzed my rating quite steadily over 2300. Of course I want to know whether I'm just in stellar form (doesn't feel like it) or whether this is a peculiarity of chess24.

Edit: Maybe it was just stellar form. My new year tournament went very well indeed ...

Edit: Now it's four years later and I am usually rated around 2600 on chess24 with peaks up to 2800. Seems like there is a steady inflation going on.

Answer (score 3):

From my own experience chess24 ratings are quite inflated. I can get a 2200 rating easy on chess24 but struggle to maintain a 1900+ rating on chess.com.

Comment: Yeah, but on chess.com it is quite difficult to find opponents above 1900. I found this limited my rating on this site.

Answer (score 3):

On chess24 I am much higher rated, around 2400+ (currently around 2440). On lichess I am around 2200. On chess.com the same.
I am FM, and my FIDE is around 2200, for reference.

Answer (score 2):

The Chess24 rating has undergone some changes over the last year, resulting on it being slightly inflated compared both ICC and Playchess ratings at the moment. This is a perception of my opponents' playing strength on my part (opinion) and my own ratings on the sites (N=1), so take it for what it's worth.

Chess 24 ratings started off at 1500, while the players who were drawn to it were relatively strong (for whatever reason), meaning people were relatively underrated in the beginning. They upped the rating at that point, and as far as I could tell and remember increased everyone's rating by 200 points on two occasions since launch.

Comment: It makes sense to me that they increased everybody's rating twice, because nowadays my rating on chess24 is actually slightly above 2400. So, another 100 points from when I posted this question. If you'll find any source for this claim, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The site is quite weird - on the one hand it’s similar to Lichess in the sense that the ratings are several hundred points lower in level than that of Chess.com; so a 2k player on Chess.com would be roughly 2200+ on Chess24. But on the other hand there are also tons of underrated players who are like 1700 but play to the level of a strong titled player as well an abundance of cheaters or auto bots due to the site’s obvious lack of cheat detection.

Answer (score 1):

Chess24 ratings are quite overstated compared to other server ratings. You would always have a +100-200 Elo higher compared to other websites.

Answer (score 1):

On ICC, and as a clubplayer, I have a rating around 1900. But on Chess24 I have now reached 2200. Now, that’s inflation!

Answer (score 0):

I found chess24 full of relatively serious players whereas playchess seemed more like hobbyists. Your style might have changed a bit where you score well against serious players.

Comment: I noticed something similar in the comparison of playchess and ICC. But as I've been playing on ICC the last few month, without any rating change, I really doubt my style changed.

Comment: It could be something to do the with the fact that you will get slightly different time scrambles on c24 due to lag and every move taking 0.2 seconds instead of 0.1 on ICC. No idea about anything else.

Comment: Well, right now I'm not even using a mouse … and I play without increment. On ICC I did use a mouse, but time scrambles still usually finished badly for me.

Comment: You inspired me to get to 2300 without using a mouse too!